# java error while connecting to oracle through eclipse

Tags: java, oracle, eclipse, database-connection

I have been trying to connect to my oracle database using eclipse but I keep getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Erreur d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

I had tried many codes but either of theme seems to work, I also checked the listener.ora file and tnsnames.ora but the information (port number, SID) are correct.
here is my code :

```
         package application;
         import java.sql.*;
         public class monInterface {


public static void main(String[] args)  {
    
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCLSYS","system","TPBDD");

        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        String sql="select * from film";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));
        rs.close();
            } 

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        
    }}}
```

and the  listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\App\db_home)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\App\db_home\bin\oraclr19.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

and the tnsnames.ora:

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
    (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

I am using oracle 10g and java se 8

so  please if someone can help me fix this problem.

Comment: are you able to connect the db using tnsalias? `sqlplus uname/pwd@tnsalias`

Comment: You should also check the listener status on db server using the `lsnrctl status` and from your system, you should use tnsping to check if you are able to connect to the tns using `tnsping yourtnsalias`

Comment: The error suggests it can't reach the listener at network level. So to rule out the simple things, is the listener running, and are that and the database are running on the same PC as Eclipse? (You probably shouldn't be connecting as SYSTEM, and you certainly shouldn't be creating objects like your `film` table under that built-in schema; create a new user and create things under that. That isn't the problem - it isn't getting that far - just general advice *8-)

Comment: Should the SID not be in the jdbc URL ?

Comment: The SID is in the URL, as the `:ORCLSYS` part. Though it should probably be the service name, as `/ORCLSYS`, assuming they are the same. It isn't getting as far as worrying about that though, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's late but i did fix my problem by using ojdbc7 instead of ojdbc6
thank you all fro your answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are connecting to incorrect SID. The SID mentioned in code is `ORCLSYS` and the one in your listener files is `CLRExtProc`. Try making the driver connection as below, I think it must work.

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:CLRExtProc","system","TPBDD");
```

Moreover if you intend to use `Thin` Driver and your SID & Service Name are same, then below format must also help.

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/CLRExtProc","system","TPBDD");
```

Comment: If the SID was wrong it would be a different error. `CLRExtProc` is a built-in one for external calls, not something you'd connect to directly. As the SID isn't in the listener the OP probably actually wants to be using the service name. But it isn't getting that far, form the error being reported.

Comment: that points to a very imp aspect, there is one more missing bit in `listener.ora` as something like this,
`CLRExtProc=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = CLRExtProc)
    )
  )`

Comment: Also checking `lsnrctl status` would help to judge of listener is actually listening for connections.

Comment: Indeed, checking the listener is covered in comments under the question. But CLRExtProc should not be changed either way, possibly a SID list should be added for ORCLSYS, but more likely they should be using service name. (And lsnrctl status would show the valid service names too, of course.)